# Dokku: cannot deploy app due to wkhtmltopdf downloading from gna

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, wkhtmltopdf, digital-ocean, dokku

I'm having an issue deploying my Rails 4 app using wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf to DigitalOcean with Dokku. My server is running Ubuntu 14.04.

When deploying, the app wants to install wkhtmltopdf; everything was OK before, but it is trying to download wkhtmltopdf via gna, which does not exist anymore.

```
remote: --2017-10-19 21:20:38--  http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb

remote: Resolving download.gna.org (download.gna.org)... 78.40.125.79

remote: Connecting to download.gna.org (download.gna.org)|78.40.125.79|:80...

Retrying...
```

Do I have to change the wkhtmltopdf source somewhere?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can run this commands on your server to [install wkhtmltopdf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556667/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-0-12-1-on-ubuntu-server#556672)

> In Ubuntu 12.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

> In Ubuntu 14.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ecometrica/servers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

> and one step after this is to reboot the server or else you will get the error: wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server .
>
> In Ubuntu 16.04 and later wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2+ can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories.

Anyway the idea is that you have to install **wkhtmltopdf** based on the [documentation](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) that you can find on their site